# Boost ptree node for all children in a json array

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I have been searching for an answer to this but cant find anything so sorry if this has been asked before. I have the following json file

```boost
{"GuiComponents": [
{
    "GuiComponent":
    {
        "screen": "WindowMain",
        "type": "class Robot",
        "filename": "robot.mesh",
        "blueprint": "Betplacement/Robot.json",
        "layer": "0",
        "position": 
        {
            "x": "0",
            "y": "0"
        }
    }
},
{
    "GuiComponent": 
    {
        "screen": "WindowTop",
        "type": "class Robot",
        "filename": "robot.mesh",
        "blueprint": "Betplacement/Robot.json",
        "layer": "0",
        "position": 
            {
            "x": "0",
            "y": "0"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Now I want to iterate over all the children in GuiComponents called GuiComponent and assign each child to a ptree node. This way I can simply pass a ptree node to anyone that wants to get the data for a specific GuiComponent without seeing all the other children. I cannot find a way to do this with get_child as it just throws a "No such node GuiComponent" exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you are trying to access the nodes with `get_child()`?

Comment: I have tried boost::property_tree::ptree child = m_tree.get_child("GuiComponents.GuiComponent") and boost::property_tree::ptree child = m_tree.get_child("GuiComponent"). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `GuiComponent` elements are stored in unnamed elements of an array; when reading JSON data, Boost.PropertyTree will ["translate" array elements into children of empty nodes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser).

Here is what you can try: search for empty nodes, and then search for elements `GuiComponent` within each node, using the [`equal_range()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp97929736-bb) method:

```
auto array_iter = m_tree.equal_range("");
for (auto i: array_iter) {
  auto gui_iter = i->second.equal_range("GuiComponent");
  for (auto gui_component: gui_iter) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

An iterator on a ptree points to a pair where the first element is the name of the node and the second element is a ptree.

Comment: Isnt returning anything of use. result.first is equal to result.second. Ta

Comment: @codetemplar I have updated my answer: since you have an array in your JSON data, ptree transforms it into unnamed nodes.